# Attaching PUT method to script in blade file

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I've a simple table with only ID and country field, trying to edit/update country data in [Bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)
I'm succcessfully able to attach the data to the modal like this:

Button:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCountry" data-country="{{$countryFilter->country}}" href="{{ $countryFilter->country }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
```

Modal:

```
div class="modal fade" id="editCountry" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editCountry" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Country</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route("admin.country-filters.update", [$countryFilter->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @method('PUT')
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="required" for="country">{{ trans('cruds.countryFilter.fields.country') }}</label>
                <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('country') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="text" name="country" id="country" value="{{ old('country', $countryFilter->country) }}" required>
                @if($errors->has('country'))
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('country') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
                <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.countryFilter.fields.country_helper') }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                    {{ trans('global.update') }}
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">{{ trans('global.cancel') }}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Attaching data script:

```
<script>
$('#editCountry').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var country = button.data('country')
    
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit ' + country)

    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(country)
    $(this).find('input').attr(country)
})
</script>
```

When I update the data for example the row that contains country Germany I get the following error:
The GERMANY method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

How can I include:

```
@method('PUT')
@csrf
```

In the request?

controller method:

```
public function update(UpdateCountryFilterRequest $request, CountryFilter $countryFilter)
{
  $countryFilter->update($request->all());
  return redirect()->route('admin.country-filters.index');
}
```

UpdateCountryFilterRequest

```
class UpdateCountryFilterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Gate::allows('country_filter_edit');
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'country' => [
                'string',
                'required',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

dd output:

```
array:3 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\Admin\CountryFilterController.php:58
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "_token" => "Vfk2d62eNZKFFHCQjLGlKEFbxCfrLHxgZJuO8ihP"
  "country" => "GermanyEdited"
]
```

Comment: You already have "@method('PUT') @csrf" correctly, your issue is with your Javascript doing strange things, is that the only code you have that is doing changes using javascript?

Comment: Yes that's the only JS code I have in file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Okay your issue is with this line of code:**

```
modal.find('.modal-body input').val(country)
```

What you are doing here is saying, *find every input inside the modal-body and change its value to $country*.

**But you are also using the blade tags:**

```
@method('PUT')
@csrf
```

**Which really translates to:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="TOKEN_CODE">
```

So you can see that the code is trying to replace the values of those 2 inputs to the value of `$country` but we need them to stay the way they are as they are very important to submitting the form correctly.

**Okay, so to correct this, you can simply change only the value of the ID you already want to change line 9 and line 10 as follows:**

```
<script>
$('#editCountry').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var country = button.data('country')
    
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit ' + country)

    //modal.find('.modal-body input').val(country)
    $('#country').val(country)
    $(this).find('input').attr(country)
})
</script>
```

And there you go, that will only change the value of the `input id="country"`, My advice is to avoid using find function, you already set an `ID=""` to all important things, just change them directly.

Comment: Your answer did take me towards the correct direction, but instead of `$('#country').val(country)` I used 
     `modal.find('.modal-body input[name="country"]').val(country)`
to define which exactly input field  and it worked

Comment: However data isn't being updated, but is created as a new entry

Comment: @JessicaKimble glad it helped you, can you please share your controller method? or perhaps post another question with the controller method include **dd(request()->all())** so I can further take a look at data is being passed and what data you would like to be updated

Comment: Controller method and dd(request()->all()) output see here please:
https://codeshare.io/wnR1vj

Comment: Not sure, I will upvote to make it neutral, meanwhile can you also paste/edit your first post with the **dd($request->all())** to see what its doing and finally, are you doing any validation in that custom **UpdateCountryFilterRequest** class?

Comment: Updated question with controller method, UpdateCountryFilterRequest, dd

Comment: Accepting the answer as the issue of including PUT in the request is resolved.